# Offload live streaming to phone or another computer?

Tags: windows-10, android, streaming, screen-sharing

I want to live stream something from an older hardware laptop that struggles to stream the screen while doing something else. So I wanted to offload the processing of the stream to either a phone or another much more capable laptop.

So is it possible to have this setup where I stream my stuff from the older laptop but use a different device to "power" the streaming process? The older laptop is running Windows 10 with the more powerful laptop running Windows 10 as well or the phone running Android 10 if that matters.

Update:
I'm open to buying additional hardware that can help with this process (maybe capture card?)

Comment: I can't think of a way that this would be possible. I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: I agree. The first machine is going to have already compressed the stream to squeeze it down USB. By that time, most of the heavy lifting is done.

Comment: @Tetsujin could something like a capture card work? I'm not familiar with consoles but I believe that's what they use since they don't support streaming out of the box

Comment: To use a capture card, first you have to feed it a picture, over HDMI etc - again, the work is already done. The biggest load on any recording/streaming structure is that the machine not only has to play the 'video' it also has to capture it, convert it & either throw it down the line or save it to disk. That's the big lift. The rest is 'easy'.

Comment: Where is the bottleneck (CPU, I/O)? What software is used for streaming?